# Summing a column by all transactions in a day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to sum up all transactions for each day in my database.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    SUM(Balance) OVER (partition by Date) AS account_total, 
    Date 
FROM tbl_FundData 
ORDER BY Date;
```

The problem with the output is if a transaction is completed at a different time it becomes its own unique sum instead of rolling into the one day. I'm not sure how to modify the query to fix this.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 (I think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems yo use DateTime as column data type so cast it as DATE :

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(Balance) OVER (partition by CAST([Date] AS DATE)) AS account_total, CAST([Date] AS DATE)
FROM tbl_FundData 
ORDER BY CAST([Date] AS DATE);
```

Also you'd better use Group By in this case as :

```
SELECT SUM(Balance) AS account_total, CAST([Date] AS DATE)
FROM tbl_FundData 
GROUP BY CAST([Date] AS DATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    SUM(Balance) OVER (partition by convert(varchar, Date, 103)) AS account_total,  
    convert(varchar, Date, 103) Date    
FROM tbl_FundData 
ORDER BY  convert(varchar,Date,103)
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT SUM(Balance) account_total 
  ,CAST(FLOOR(CAST(IssueDate  AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) IssueDate
  FROM tbl_FundData
  GROUP BY
  CAST(FLOOR(CAST(IssueDate  AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
  ORDER BY 
  CAST(FLOOR(CAST(IssueDate  AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a timestamp as well in your date that's why you get unique values when you sum. Use this:

```
SELECT sum(balance)
FROM tbl_FundData 
GROUP BY convert(date ,date, 106)
```

106 is a format for date. But you could use whatever.